# Laravel 4.2 validation: required_unless

Tags: php, validation, laravel, custom-validators

Recently I have been learning Laravel and came accross validator problem that would be solved by using validator rule [`required_unless` from Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-required-unless):

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array(
        'social_id' => $social_id,
        'login_by' => $login_by
    ), array(
        'social_id' => 'required_unless:login_by,manual',
        'login_by' => "in:manual,google,facebook, stack_exchange, myspace"
    )
);
```

Problem is that I use Laravel 4.2 and this validation rule is not implemented jet.

Is there any other validating rule I could use or any other way?

If not, how would I write a custom validation rule and where would I put it?

Edit: I could do:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array(
        'social_id' => $social_id,
        'login_by' => $login_by
    ), array(
        'social_id' => 'required_if:login_by,google,facebook, stack_exchange, myspace',
        'login_by' => "in:manual,google,facebook, stack_exchange, myspace"
    )
);
```

...but this is just a workaround not an elegant permanent solution.

Comment: 4.2 or 5.2 what do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply extend the Validator with the `extend` method.

Something like this

```
Validator::extend('required_unless', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    // Implement your version of required_unless here
});
```

And even steal a bit of logic from L5.2 [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L860)

You can see the doc on extend [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Laravel implementation references $this->data. Since the function you suggested me to write isn't extending Validator I can't use that, can I? Does that mean have to make my own class that extends Validator?

Comment: No you can't use `$this->data` inside the closure, if you need some stuff from the base Validator, then yes you need your own Validator class look at the doc link above, section "Extending The Validator Class"

Comment: Any suggestion where should I put that class?

Comment: A "Validators" folder inside app seems convenient. I don't think that's PSR4 yet so check on autoloading in your composer.json file